# Native Brightcove for Android

Tags: android, brightcove

I successfully implemented the bright cove in native Android. But Currently am facing some problem as,

1. When i press the video and Press HOME button, the Video starts from First
2. When i lock the screen and the unlock the screen, the Video starts from First.

Did any one come through this problem. Can share the knowledge.

THanks.

Comment: I do not understand your problem. What do you mean "Video starts from First"? Are you expecting the video should start where you left it? Also, what version/device of Android are you working on?

Comment: Yes the video should start from where i left, i am testing on Android 2.3

Comment: are you using the latest SDK? I just tested the Sample Template comes with the Brightcove App Cloud Workshop. The video actually works as expected. (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brightcove.android.katama.previewapp)

Comment: What version of Brightcove you had tested?

Comment: I believe I tested on Samsung Galaxy 2 with Android 2.3, with the latest Brightcove workshop.

Answer (score 0):

Are you extending the BrightCovePlayer or BrightCovePlayerFragment in your implementation? It will be nice if you share the code snippet for the player setup.